# HMT: multiple collection_select - assign to a column in the linking record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, form-helpers

If I have a `HMT` like this:

```
class Rate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :adjustments
  has_many :deductions, through: :adjustments
end
```

I've noticed that doing a

```
= f.collection_select :deduction_ids, current_user.deductions.all, :id, :name, {}, multiple: true
```

and then

```
params.require(:rate).permit(deduction_ids: [])
```

and finally

```
def create
  @rate = Rate.new rate_params
  @rate.save
end
```

Seems to create all the necessary `adjustment` records to join our `@rate` to the selected `deductions`, great!

Now, I've added an extra column to `adjustments`, a `type`. Every set of select fields will belong to a specific type. There could be two `deduction` selects on a page but each one for a different `adjustment.type`

Is there a way to create a hidden input or pass the `type` into the `collection_select` in a way that will be processed by the `Rate.new rate_params` call?

This is the source code of the form

```
= form_for @rate do |f|
  - if @rate.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@rate.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this rate from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @rate.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message

  %h3 Deductions
  %h4 Pre-tax
  .field
    = f.collection_select :deduction_ids, current_user.deductions.all, :id, :name, {}, multiple: true
  %h4 post-tax
  .field
    = f.collection_select :deduction_ids, current_user.deductions.all, :id, :name, {}, multiple: true
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

Comment: can u show your form ?

Comment: Sure! https://gist.github.com/zinefer/07e8eee1f3fdf37bf32cfd3daaa8bf40

Comment: you are using nested_attributes concept to store deduction right?

Comment: I haven't configured any `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on `deductions`, `rates` or `adjustments`. I would assume I would need to configure that if I wanted to change a `deduction` from a `rate` but that's not what I am looking for here. Instead, I want to tell rails to insert ajustments with a particular type.

Comment: I'm thinking what I want to do is too complicated for rails to solve for me and I should just use two different param names and "manually" parse them in the controller.

Comment: deduction_ids is currently attribute of rate model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156289/discussion-between-refeniz-and-krishnar).